# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out (SQL: select * from `sessions` where `id` = Me2dEG11Zq4pJBhzCoWlhZwZuWPebKdGPLyhuleg limit 1)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, server

I have a problem, my web site was working without problems, but when I enter any product, the web site does not work and gives this error
I made

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan key:generate
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan make:command FlushSessions
php artisan session:flush
```

And I Deleted the data into the sessions table inside the Database
But the problem has not been resolved

Comment: At least error message contains syntax error, because ID should be wrapped in quotes. Also check database connection configuration, maybe they are wrongly configured

Comment: Why not share more details, like the code involved and your attempts to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue just in `.env` file change the value of `DB_HOST` to `127.0.0.1`

"change `DB_HOST=mysql` to `DB_HOST=127.0.0.1`"